# File says it doesn't exist but it is right there

Tags: filesystem

I am doing some crypto testing with openssl on ubuntu 12.04 and I have a directory build with the following specs:

```
$home/   
  demoCA/
    certs
    index.txt
    serial
    openssl.cnf
    newcerts/
    crl/
```

And everytime I run a command, specifically this:

```
openssl ca -in server.csr -out server.crt -cert ca.crt -keyfile ca.key -config openssl.cnf
```

it tells me:

> I am unable to access the ./demoCA/newcerts directory
>
> ./demoCA/newcerts: No such file or directory

There are a few commands I run before this to set it up and I'd be glad to outline them if that would be helpful but I have no idea why it won't find that one directory.  Any suggestions?

This is the lab I am running along with:  [http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs/Crypto/Crypto_PublicKey/Crypto_PublicKey.pdf](http://www.cis.syr.edu/%7Ewedu/seed/Labs/Crypto/Crypto_PublicKey/Crypto_PublicKey.pdf)

Comment: Try using absolute paths, to avoid problems due to automatic working directory changes, sometimes made by programs (maybe `openssl`). Make your command as specific as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It searches in demoCA.

According to your Filestructure, your directory is called democa.

You should probably take care of the case sensitive directory names.

Comment: why is this accepted answer?, directory hierarchy shows demoCA not democa